# Long being treated as int in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, int, long-integer

I have defined a variable as a long, and when I try to use it as one in my array it keeps throwing an error saying my value is outside of the int range. Well, no kidding, it is a long, and I defined it as one.

Below is my code. In the second class, LoanOfficer, you will find the second applicant, Bill Gates, which has the annual income of 3,710,000,000 which is throwing the error.

```
public class Applicant {
    private String name;
    private int creditScore;
    private long annualIncome;
    private int downPayment;
    private boolean status;

    public Applicant(String name, int creditScore, long annualIncome,
            int downPayment) {
        this.name = name;
        this.creditScore = creditScore;
        this.annualIncome = annualIncome;
        this.downPayment = downPayment;
        this.status = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCreditScore() {
        return creditScore;
    }

    public long getAnnualIncome() {
        return annualIncome;
    }

    public int getDownPayment() {
        return downPayment;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}

public class LoanOfficer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Applicant[] applicants = {
                new Applicant("MC Hammer", 400, 25000, 5000),
                new Applicant("Bill Gates", 850, 3710000000, 500000),
                new Applicant("MC Hammer", 400, 25000, 5000),
                new Applicant("MC Hammer", 400, 25000, 5000), };
    }
}
```

Comment: put an L at the end of the number,

Answer (score 15):

You need the `L` suffix on numbers that are treated as longs:

```
new Applicant("Bill Gates", 850, 3710000000L, 500000)
```

If the `L` suffix is missing, the compiler will treat the literal as an `int`.

Comment: @user2217408 To make this the main answer for the question, accept it!

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify 3710000000 as a long literal by appending `L`:

```
new Applicant("Bill Gates", 850, 3710000000L, 500000),
```

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int

Comment: @Colin DeClue It's just that someone clicked the upvote button before he was upvoted, causing mine to appear before his. Posts appear in vote order, not in time order.

Comment: Besides, the purpose of the comments is not to talk about whose answer is better, it's to comment on a particular answer!

Comment: @gparyani You can order how answers appear.

Answer (score 2):

Change 3710000000 to 3710000000L. The problem is that without the `L`, Java will treat it as an `int`.